# How do I include a variable in a multidimensional JSON string?

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to include a variables inside a multidimensional JSON string.  I think I need to use json_encode but i'm not sure how to go about it.

```
$clientID = 123456;
$body = "<h1 id='heading1'>This is just a standard html message.</h1>";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
    \"subject\": \"How Did We Do\",
    \"clientId\": $clientID,
    \"assignedUserId\": 2988,
    \"public\": false,
    \"activity\": [
    {
      \"public\": false,
      \"comment\": {
          \"body\": $body
      }
    }
    ]
}");
```

Comment: Why are you manually creating a json string?

Comment: For an API call, i don't know another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make an array and use `json_encode()` to encode it.

```
$array = [
    'subject' => 'How Did We Do',
    'clientId' => $clientID,
    'assignedUserId' => 2988,
    'public' => false,
    'activity' => [
        [
            'public' => false,
            'comment' => [
                'body' => $body
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($array));
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to try this!